# Binding a function to a combobox in python tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am a newbie to python and tkinter and I ran into a problem as I was practicing on Combobox. I wrote this code with two dependent combobox. If in the first combobox, 'Jan' is selected, the second one will be enabled and automatically give 'J' as the only choice to choose from.

When I ran my code and selected 'Jan' in Combobox1, the combobox 2 was enabled, but it didn't have any value (in this case 'J').

Can someone help me with this?

````
import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

month = StringVar()
combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = month)
combobox1.config(values = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'August'))

combobox1.pack()

date = StringVar()
global comb2
comb2 = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = date)
comb2.pack()
comb2.config(state=DISABLED)

def comb1_selected(*args):
    if (combobox1.current() != -1 ):
        comb2.config(state='normal')

        if combobox1.current() == "Jan":
            comb2.config(values=('J'))




combobox1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comb1_selected)

root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Combobox.current()` returns the index of the selected item. In your case it is `0`.

If you want to get the value of the selected item, you should use `Combobox.get()`.

```
def comb1_selected(*args):
    if (combobox1.current() != -1 ):

        print('current: ' + str(combobox1.current())) #current: 0
        print('get: ' + combobox1.get()) #get: Jan

        comb2.config(state='normal')
        if combobox1.get() == 'Jan':
            comb2.config(values=('J'))
```